# What sort of site is 'JugonesTop"?

Tags: discussion

This recent [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/202813/23547) prompted [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/202858/23547), to which a [comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/202813/when-do-you-need-to-make-an-strength-athletics-check-to-climb-when-you-have-a#comment555933_202858) asked "Where are you getting your quotes from? I cant find them in the PHB".

In attempting to source the putative rules quotes, I stumbled upon this intriguing [page](https://www.jugonestop.com/pregunta/133466/cuando-necesitas-hacer-un-chequeo-de-fuerza-atletismo-para-subir-cuando-tienes-una-velocidad-de-ascenso).  It is a complete Spanish translation, and not a bad one at that, of our site's page - much like you will sometimes see a question copied word-for-word on quora.  There are web adds on the page, so the most innocuous interpretation would be that this is just an enterprise to send bots out to harvest / scrape web content, translate it, and then sell web advertisement space (and perhaps promote the translation software, "Yandex").

While most of the poster's names have been changed (to give the impression that this is a legitimate site with actual members?), mine hasn't - and there is a link to my actual rpg stacks member page.  Should I be concerned about this?

The page says that it is "Powered by StackExchange" - I doubt that arrangement is consensual.  Does someone at StackExchange want to know about this?

Is there some aspect to this that is more sinister than selling web adds?  Perhaps people who think this is a real community site make an account and then something is done with their information?

Comment: Related from MSE: [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177)

Answer (score 14):

#### It's a Stack Exchange scraper, but in Spanish.

This is explained fully in this meta.se post: [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/674198), but here is the basic explanation of what the site is:

> ### What is a "scraper" and why is that bad?
>
> Historically, SCRAPER here on Stack Exchange meant "Stack Content Republishers Attributing Poorly and/or Excelling at Ranking." More generally, a scraper is another website which copies content from our sites either by scraping directly from our pages, accessing the information through our API, or some other means. In principle, there's actually nothing wrong with doing this. Our content is licensed under [Creative Commons BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) and is freely redistributable, so long as they follow the [attribution requirements](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) and link back to us as the source. Some sites, however, do not follow these rules or bring up other concerns in the process.

The site you mention appears to be doing this, but translating our posts into Spanish. The meta answer linked above goes into detail about what you should do about this, so refer to the instructions there for next steps. Giving it a cursory inspection, it appears to be in the "do not report" category, and if, as you say, the translations are actually good, it may actually be providing some value to Spanish speaking readers.

Comment: "*answer linked above goes into detail about what you should do about this*" protip - there is almost nothing that can be done about these. SE used to encourage users to report scrapers that did not respect contribution but have completely abandoned this now.